# Not using 'like' for similes --- where does this come from?

Tags: british-english, simile

I just got back some feedback on a piece of work of mine from a proofreader. One of his comments is that I use *like* in similes a lot, and I shouldn't do that --- I should be using *as if* instead; he says that *like* most accurately means *is similar to*. For example, in this phrase I used:

> It accelerated away like a bullet down the barrel of a gun.

I've never come across this before. I know that my proofreader speaks fairly old-fashioned British English, and I speak fairly modern British English, and as far as I'm aware, *like* is perfectly acceptable here. But I'm not aware that it was ever *not* acceptable (in relatively recent times).

Can anyone find my a reference for what he's talking about here? Some basic searching doesn't come up with anything, but *like* is practically ungoogleable.

Comment: Your proofreader is a bit "overopinionated". Or perhaps you misunderstood him - he might have simply meant that if you replaced *some* instances of ***like*** with ***as if*** this could help introduce some variety in what might otherwise have been an intrusively noticeable [over-]usage. But in your specific example I think ***as if*** would appear antiquated and stilted, so if that was one he suggested changing, get a different proofreader.

Comment: Oh, we're both well aware that this is opinion, and I'm totally not going to change this because I like it the way it is. I'm just curious as to where his opinion's coming from.

Comment: [O, it came o'er my ear **like** the sweet sound,. That breathes upon a bank of violets](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/plays/twn_1_1.html). If it was good enough for Shakespeare, it's good enough for me. Again, ***as if*** would be a bit "weird" there. But as you say, it's all just a matter of opinion (apart from the request to establish whether anyone with any *credibility* has ever put forward such an extreme position as your proofreader).

Comment: I have seen this advice before. I think it's one of these zombie rules, like *"never split an infinitive"* or *"don't use got"*, although there are obviously some cases where *"as if"* is an improvement over *"like"*.

Comment: Yes, but where does it come from?

Comment: There's some zombie somewhere whose job is making all these rules?

Comment: ... but your proofreader's opinion, is not *merely* opinion---it's also bad opinion---it doesn't improve your sentence, but instead diminishes its readability.

Comment: Yes, I know that; that's not what I'm asking (I've edited the post to clarify). I want to know the _source_ of this opinion.

Comment: Certainly like it's like possible to overuse "like".  Like yaknowatimean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this advice at [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-as), and probably many other places on the internet. The rule (which seems to have been generally followed before the 20th century) is: use *as if* when it introduces a clause containing a verb, and *like* when it introduces a noun phrase.

Consider one of Grammar Girl's examples. The first two are both correct, while the third is supposedly wrong:

> He throws like a raccoon.
>
> He throws as if he were a raccoon.
>
> *He throws like he was a raccoon.

In the 19th century, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+if+he+were%2Cas+if+he+was%2Clike+he+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20he%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20he%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20he%20was%3B%2Cc0) shows that people never (or very rarely) used *like* for clauses containing verbs. So this was good advice in the early part of the 20th century, when this use of *like* was grammatically new, and would have been considered out of place if used in formal writing.

Now, the grammar has changed, and *like* sounds perfectly fine in these sentences to me. However, you still get people promulgating this rule. And it looks like some of them (like your proofreader), for whom this rule is not part of their natural grammar, have overgeneralized it to *never use like in similes*. This was never a rule of English grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the source --- but that looks like _American_ English, which has different rules, so it may not be strictly applicable to British English.

Comment: It does look very like what he was talking about, though.

Comment: [Here's](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-if-and-as-though) the same advice from *Cambridge Dictionaries Online* (toned down—don't use *like* in formal contexts). I don't think AmE/BrE are very different here.

Comment: Peter has utterly explained the situation.  All that remains to be said the proofreader is a bit naive.